# How rewrite gocov command to go tool cover?

Tags: unit-testing, go, code-coverage

I have following command:

```
${GOPATH}/bin/gocov test ./... 2>test | ${GOPATH}/bin/gocov report
```

How this command will look like if I use `go tool cover`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since go 1.10 `go tool coverage` supports recursive package bypass

```
 go test ./... -coverprofile=coverage.out
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me from here https://forum.golangbridge.org/t/how-to-do-go-test-coverage-for-system-testing/6479/3

```
go test -coverprofile=cover.out -coverpkg=server \
    && go tool cover -html=cover.out
```